# arcpy.CopyFeatures_management() gives ERROR 000732?

Tags: arcpy, shapefile, arcgis-10.2, table, error-000732

I'm using ArcGIS Desktop 10.2.2.

I have a feature class in a geodatabase that from time to time I want to update with new data in an excel table.  I wrote the following script to convert an excel table into a shapefile and overwrite the old feature class with that new shapefile.

Note: Hardwiring the Input_Table and Output_FC variables didn't help.

```
# Get tool input parameters
#wspace = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)           # workspace
Input_Table = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)   # CSV file with new / updated points
Output_FC = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)         # Original Feature Class Overwritten by NEW Shapefile in final step (CopyFeatures)

import arcpy, sys
from arcpy import env

#Overwrite Old Files (False=No, True=Yes)
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

# Set the local variables
wspace = r"Q:\GW\EC1210WQAEH_QESEA\CSSP_ATL\Users\vanvulpenc\CSV_to_Shapefile\temp_workspace"
x_coords = "Lng"
y_coords = "Lat"
output_Layer = "output_Layer"
saved_Layer = "To_Shapefile.lyr"

# Set the spatial reference
spRef = arcpy.SpatialReference("NAD 1983 (CSRS)") 

# Make the XY event layer
arcpy.MakeXYEventLayer_management(Input_Table, x_coords, y_coords, output_Layer, spRef)

# Save to a layer file
arcpy.SaveToLayerFile_management(output_Layer, saved_Layer)

#===============================================================================
# Copy features to shapefile

arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(wspace+saved_Layer, Output_FC)
#===============================================================================

print 'Data Conversion Complete'
```

My script generates the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Q:\GW\EC1210WQAEH_QESEA\CSSP_ATL\Users\vanvulpenc\Scripts\CSV_to_Shapefile.py", line 41, in <module>
    arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(wspace+saved_Layer, Output_FC)
  File "c:\program files (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.2\arcpy\arcpy\management.py", line 2429, in CopyFeatures
    raise e
ExecuteError: Failed to execute. Parameters are not valid.
ERROR 000732: Input Features: Dataset Q:\GW\EC1210WQAEH_QESEA\CSSP_ATL\Users\vanvulpenc\CSV_to_Shapefile\temp_workspaceTo_Shapefile.lyr does not exist or is not supported
WARNING 000725: Output Feature Class: Dataset Q:\GW\EC1210WQAEH_QESEA\CSSP_ATL\Users\vanvulpenc\CSV_to_Shapefile\MWQStations.gdb\MWQStations_NS already exists.
Failed to execute (CopyFeatures).
```

Answer (score 1):

In your code you have set:

```
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = 1
```

but from its [documentation](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/analyze/arcpy-classes/env.htm) `arcpy.env` expects a Boolean (`True` or `False`) rather than an Integer for its `overwriteOutput` property.

Try this instead:

```
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
```

I am also suspicious of this path being reported in your error message:

`Q:\GW\EC1210WQAEH_QESEA\CSSP_ATL\Users
anvulpenc\CSV_to_Shapefile  emp_workspaceTo_Shapefile.lyr`

The missing letters and inserted spaces suggest that your backspaces are not being escaped by using an `r` in front of a pathname somewhere.  I am suspicious that the precise code that you have presented may not be what was run to produce that error message.

---

It also looks like you are trying to provide a layer file to [CopyFeatures](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/copy-features.htm) when it expects "Feature Layer; Raster Catalog Layer".

Instead of:

```
wspace = r"Q:\GW\EC1210WQAEH_QESEA\CSSP_ATL\Users\vanvulpenc\CSV_to_Shapefile\temp_workspace"
arcpy.SaveToLayerFile_management(output_Layer, saved_Layer)
arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(wspace+saved_Layer, Output_FC)
```

try simply:

```
wspace = r"Q:\GW\EC1210WQAEH_QESEA\CSSP_ATL\Users\vanvulpenc\CSV_to_Shapefile\temp_workspace"
arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(saved_Layer, r"{0}\{1}".format(wspace,Output_FC))
```

I have used Python string formatting to set the full path for your output.

Comment: Thanks, that was the precise code used but now that I've changed the overwriteOutput to = True I'm getting a new error (above) suggesting the problem is that the feature class I'm trying to overwrite already exists.

Comment: @Waterman If you are getting a new error then that should be researched/asked as a new question.  Try hardwiring values for `Input_Table` and `Output_FC` while you are testing.

Comment: New question posted here:  https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/270392/background-server-threw-exception-in-arcmap-python-window-after-makexyeventlaye?noredirect=1#comment430178_270392

Comment: Hardwiring the parameters results in the same error as above.

Comment: @Waterman I think you should edit your question to reflect that hardwiring so that potential answerers do not need to configure a Python script tool to test your code.