# Syntax Error related to File Path / Name in ArcPy Script

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.2, syntaxerror

I'm using ArcGIS Desktop 10.2.2.

I'm getting the following error when I run a script in Arc.

```
SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal
```

The error message points to the line where I set my workspace variable "wspace".

Here are the relevant portions of my code:

```
# Set the local variables
wspace = r"Q:\GW\EC1210WQAEH_QESEA\CSSP_ATL\Users\vanvulpenc\CSV_to_Shapefile\temp_workspace"
x_coords = "Lng"
y_coords = "Lat"
output_Layer = "output_Layer"
saved_Layer = "To_Shapefile.lyr"
```

Then later in my script the one line that references the "wspace" variable is:

```
arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(wspace+saved_Layer, Output_FC)
```

Is there a better way to format my path perhaps?

Comment: There is a lot of code here that is not related to the specific question that you are asking.  Please review [Writing code snippets to get quicker answers?](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4312).

Comment: That is not the line that is throwing the error.  Wasn't it coming from CopyFeatures?  You need just a few more lines for a suitable code snippet in this instance.

Comment: @PolyGeo - that was the error in my original question: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/270057/arcpy-copyfeatures-management-gives-error-000732  Next, following your advice, I ran it from the Python window as per this question: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/270392/background-server-threw-exception-in-arcmap-python-window-after-makexyeventlayer?noredirect=1#270392

Comment: @PolyGeo - Next, I noticed the original error message showed I lacked a backslash between my "wspace" and my "saved_Layer" so that's why only one line of code here.  With this question all I'm trying to do is zero in on the one line of code that's currently being flagged in the error message.  All the rest of my code can be found in the first question.

Comment: Please remember that each question here needs to be standalone.  New questions can come out of existing questions (and include a link back to them for optional reading) but should not be required reading to understand them.  Potential answerers, who are all volunteering their time, may or may not read any of your past questions, or comments on any questions, and so everything important to understanding your question needs to be in the question body - see https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3353/115

Comment: @PolyGeo OK but this question was only set up as per your request so that you could then explain further use Python string formatting to build paths.

Comment: @PolyGeo - I have added more code.  Hopefully not too much.  Hopefully not too little.

Comment: The test of a code snippet is to see whether, when run, it produces the error that you are asking about.  If not, then it needs more attention.  Since you have now accepted an answer, my advice would be to keep thinking about presenting code snippets that illustrate precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck rather than copy/pastes from/of your full code.

Comment: For future reference: Python FAQ - [Why can’t raw strings end with a backslash?](https://docs.python.org/2/faq/design.html#why-can-t-raw-strings-r-strings-end-with-a-backslash)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have everything set up correctly.  Simply take the '\' character off the end of the variable workspace:

```
wspace = r"Q:\GW\EC1210WQAEH_QESEA\CSSP_ATL\Users\vanvulpenc\CSV_to_Shapefile\temp_workspace"
```

Python will see \" as an escape character - for reference, if you wanted to include that backslash at the end of the string (which you don't want to here), you would end the line with \\".

Now, if you need to join this with a filename later on - you can do this one of two ways.  First, you can join them like this:

```
output = wspace + '\\' + layer
```

Note the double backslash, then call the output variable in your arcpy call.  Better still, import os at the beginning of your script, and use os.path.join inside your arcpy call:

```
os.path.join(wspace, layer)
```

That will eliminate any errors.

Comment: Long story, but I put the final backslash there because when I used the wspace variable later in the script (i.e. "wspace + layer") it was combining the final directory in the wspace path with the name of my layer.  Trying to separate them with (wspace + r"\"+ layer) didn't help either, it only caused the same error as above.

Comment: I see - try either of the above options, updated.

Comment: I agree with @AlecZ on getting rid of the final backslash. Using os.path.join instead of merging two path strings is better because it will make sure the merge is done correctly.

Comment: @AlexZ  - That works.  Very helpful and to the point.  Thank you.

Comment: String concatenation using `+` is troubling enough, but path construction should always be done with os.path.join.

Comment: I agree with @Tom that `os.path.join` is a good way to construct paths but I usually prefer to use Python string formatting like `r"{0}\{1}".format(wspace,Output_FC))`.

Comment: I appreciate the helpful hints.

Comment: @PolyGeo, [Advanced String Formatting (PEP 3101)](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3101/) is the recommended way of compiling strings; however, using it for path construction is risky, because it's platform-dependent. os.path.join abstracts away the peculiarities of the operating system and makes the code more portable. It's less relevant if one is working within ArcPy, but it's good practice if one intends to work more broadly with Python.

Comment: @Tom I agree - it just depends on where you fall on the ArcPy to Python developer spectrum.